# Steam doesn't start after update

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, steam

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I installed Steam about 2 months ago, without using the 32 bit libs or anything. When it last prompted me for updates (yesterday), I didn't to update it and I haven't been able to start it since then.

Output when run from terminal:

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140504021210_1.dmp
/home/elie/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755: 18302 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/elie/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/elie/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/elie/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140504021213_1.dmp
/home/elie/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755: 18432 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-548166d2-e868-46b4-ac37-b548b2140503
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-132434a3-69e3-4dff-96fe-a2be32140503
```

I tried installing 32 bit libs, updating my system, upgrading, reinstalling, deleting `appcache`.

What can I do?

Comment: I can mostly solve this by launching with `STEAM_RUNTIME=1 steam` about 5 times. Sometimes I click the launcher 10 times in a row instead. I've heard mention that you can reinstall graphic drivers, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: @Lynob, Please do not post an answer as an edit. I have moved it to a community wiki answer. For you to get the reputation, you should post as an answer and flag mine for deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two weeks ago there was a [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217937) on [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org) about an extremly similar issue. The outputs you had was identical in all ways possible, only thing was he didn't have the issue during update, but rather installation.

According to this post there may be a difference between installing Steam from a PPA, Software Center, Synaptic or official DEB package. Installing it through all those sources you can be successful, according to the post.

Another very common issue is that the graphics drivers are "incorrect". Speaking from own experience, changing drivers and reinstalling can solve the issue. By changing I mean switch from Open Sourced drivers to Closed and vise versa.

When reinstalling Steam, if you don't want to delete your game data you should be able to follow ChrisR's suggestion of saving the `SteamApps` folder and then replace the new contents with your old save.

P.S. I apologize as this maybe should have been posted like a comment. The thing is, I don't have enough rep for that so I hope you'll except my vague attempt to an answer :)

Comment: seems that changing the graphic drivers, going back to xorg solved this issue *(weirdest solution ever)* and I shall accept your answer

Comment: @Fischer What exactly do you mean by "going back to xorg"?

Comment: @Sparhawk I meant using xorg instead of fglrx which I usually use

Comment: @Fischer I'm so confused. Doesn't fglrx run in X?

Comment: @Sparhawk I don't know what happened, I had to use xorg, only then steam started, then it updated then I reused fglrx and steam worked

Comment: @Fischer Okay. I guess it's probably specific to your GPU anyway. I'm having the same problem, but it's intermittent. Hopefully this fixes it for you in the long term.

Comment: @Sparhawk you didn't solve the issue? did you try my solution?

Comment: @Fischer It's still intermittent, but I don't use fglrx. I've got an Optimus laptop, but the integrated Intel GPU is the only thing running when I try to launch Steam.

Comment: @Sparhawk you could try switching to fglrx and restart your pc just to see if it would work.

Comment: @Fischer But if I don't have an ATI card…

Comment: @Sparhawk  you don't have any additional drivers other than xorg?

Comment: @Fischer As I said before, I have an Optimus laptop, meaning that I switch between the integrated Intel and discrete Nvidia. I have drivers for the latter, but I've had so many problems setting Optimus up on my computer that I'm petrified to reinstall the drivers.

Comment: @Sparhawk oh i see! look could you try to delete your xorg file and regenerate it, I think I had the same exact issue happening to me in 13.10, there's a strange relationship between steam update manager and graphic drivers, so that when you force it to stop, it won't start, at least that what I think, regenerating xorg may fix  it

Comment: @Fischer You mean xorg.conf? Mine are pretty bare, but do include some custom stuff in them. I don't really want to mess with them either, although perhaps it's worth just to troubleshoot. Anyway, Steam is starting up most times after clicking the icon 10 times, so I think I'd prefer not to mess too much with my fragile system. :) Thanks though.

Comment: @Sparhawk yes i mean xorg.conf and you could back it up if you want, if you ever find a solution to your problem, please share it here  :)

Comment: @Fischer Thanks, will do. I actually suspect that it's getting better by itself, but I'll definitely post here if it changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Community Wiki answer of the OP's answer which was in the question.

---

> I had to change my display server to Xorg. When I did, Steam opened and downloaded the update.
>
> I went back to `fglrx` and steam is now working.

Comment: I have edited the OP's answer so it is more clear. The original answer should be available in the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem in the past (refusing to upgrade steam), I had to completely reinstall steam.  You can save your currently installed Steam games by going into:

```
[name of steam folder]/SteamApps
```

and saving everything inside that folder.  Once you reinstall steam, just copy the contents back into the same directory (e.g. `Steam/SteamApps`).  Then, restart Steam and you should be good to go.

Comment: but I did try to reinstall it, many times, didn't work, using apt-get, using synaptic and using the latest deb from their site, i did remove it and reinstall it, I just didn't remove the games folder, apt-get doesn't do that by default, didn't solve it

Comment: @Fischer Did you also delete the Steam files in your home folder?

Comment: @Sparhawk didnt have to, going back to xorg solved the problem mysteriously